# Spider for a messenger

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, messenger

I want to extract the channels information of [Bale](https://bale.ai) messenger.(very similar to telegram) It's an Iranian messenger which doesn't give developers any API. So I should write a spider myself. I searched and I found out [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) will help my to do it. However my problem is that Bale take the number and send a code to that phone number for its authentication(just like telegram). I don't know how to handle this authentication in my spider. Can you please help me how to authenticate correctly? Or what is the better solution for extracting information of its channel?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess we cant handle direct authentication using scrapy I guess.But with given credentials we can access it.

Check [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) for more information on handling login staff.

Comment: Thank you. But what is another way for crawling to handle direct authentication?